# Select a specific range from table using hibernate criteria

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to fetch *n* rows at a time from a table, but I don't know how to proceed. I looked at both the Criteria api and the Restrictions api, but I haven't found anything like it. So, is it possible in Hibernate? Is it possible in MySQL at all?

The table has an ID, but is autogenerated from the database and it is not so reliable (I mean, there can be a lot of missing numbers from two successive IDs). Also, there is a data column, so I can surely order the results by this column in ascending/descending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do with setFirstResult(setFirstRow) and setMaxResults(setNumberOfRecordsTofetchAtaTime) methods in Hibernate Criteria.

**Example**

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Example.class);
criteria.setFirstResult(setFirstRow);
criteria.setMaxResults(setNumberOfRecordsTofetchAtaTime);
List<Example> list=criteria.list();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. What they mean by `setFirstRow`? For example, suppose that `setFirstRow = 200` and `setMaxResult = 100`, the query returns the rows from 200 to 300?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it in a bit and then accept your answer. I've seen this method before but the official documentations sucks. For example, what should be the result in various scenarios (`setFirstRow <= 0`, `setMaxResult <= 0`)?

Comment: If SetFirstRow <=0 (and/or) setMaxResult=0, it will not fetch any value from DB(not throw error also). If setMaxResult < 0, DB will throw error.

Comment: Thanks again. How do you get these infos? I don't read anything similar in the official documentation.